Cannot SSH to Pi4B from Mac

Mac: MacBook Air M1 chip running Sonoma 14.5
Pi4B: flashed SD card with SSH enabled, no WiFi network loaded (just want to focus on Ethernet connection)
Connection: Pi >> Ethernet cable >> crossover adapter >> USB-C adapter >> Mac USB-C port
Pi Eth lights: Green (L) and Yellow (R)
On Mac, Internet sharing is turned off
Laptop is connected to my home router

I have been at this for two days and cannot get anything to work. I have followed the insturctions EXACTLY from a few tutorials. Even the official one https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/remote-access.html#resolve-raspberrypi-local-with-mdns is not working (when it tells you to ping all i get returned is the other Pi i have on my WiFi network). The only way to set the IP address is by hooking up a keyboard and monitor and manually going through the GUI. Editing the /etc/dhcpcd.conf didnt work on the terminal. I cannot find a file or anything to allow me to flash a raspbian OS and immediately enable a wired SSH connection.
The problem is: there is no way to determine what IP address the Pi has assigned itself when I plug in the ethernet. There is no discernible way to set a static IP (192.168.99.2 for the Pi) to allow it to talk to the laptop (192.168.99.1). I have the laptop setup for IPv4 Configure Manual, with IP of 192.168.99.1 and subnet 255.255.255.0
The only way I can get this to connect is by manually connecting a monitor and keyboard to the Pi and using the GUI. I would like to know how to have this setup so I dont have to do this every time I setup a new Pi (I will be setting up >20 of these). Thank you!
UPDATE: Thank you Milliways for the setup advice, I removed the crossover adaptor and it worked fine on a different pi with static IP.
This is what the new Pi defaults to. Without plugging in the monitor I cannot know what IP address the Laptop has assigned the Pi.

Here is the setup for the Wired connection. Is there something wrong here? (ethernet is not connected at the time of the screenshot)


Your Ethernet cable and adapters should be functioning properly.
Double-check the file names and content, as typos can prevent the configurations from being applied.
Verify that your Mac's firewall settings are not blocking the connection.

This is about understanding how tcp/ip netmasks work.

I’m voting to close this question because:  OP said, "I have followed the insturctions [sic] EXACTLY from a few tutorials."  Ha ha ha... I'll guess the problem is that you're reading the wrong tutorials! This appears to be a question about macOS & networking - nothing at all to do w/ Raspberry Pi. Sounds like you have failed to set the Remote Login property on your "Sonoma" Mac, in addition to mangling your Link-Local IP addresses as answered here. Sheesh!

"there is no way to determine what IP address the Pi has assigned itself when I plug in the ethernet" the Pi DOES NOT assign - your router does and you can configure the router to always assign the same address.
No need to know IP hostname.local works!
"crossover adapter" not needed!
"Ethernet cable crossover adapter >> USB-C adapter >> Mac USB-C port"
should work (assuming the Mac is correctly configured for Ethernet over USB) but the Pi would only have a Link-local address e.g. 169.… NOT normal private address - NO need for static address.
Of course the easiest way is to connect the Pi to the same network as the Mac and your router will allocate an address  but you can still use hostname.local

Thank you. The reason I am not using WiFi is because I will need to connect to this system in the field using a wired connection. Provided I setup my Mac with a manual address of 192.168.99.1, how do I SSH into the Pi? It seems, based on your answer, that the Pi is not allowing an ethernet connection. If I flash a new raspbian OS to the SD and boot the pi with the ethernet connected, I cannot see an IP for the Pi by doing sudo nmap -sn 192.168.99.0/24. So from a fresh flash I cannot find out what address to use to connect.  Thanks for the crossover advice, I took it off and it works!

Who said anything about WiFi - use Ethernet to router.

DO NOT ask new questions in Comments! Edit your question which seems to have additional constraints you did not mention. Did you ACTUALLY try any of the methods I suggested? If so post diagnostics.

first time. ill edit the question. I did try them, but I still cannot ssh into the Pi without the IP address. hostname.local did not work at all. I tried pinging and connecting and nothing. Images above of the config. Thank you
